# HTTPS setup problem with Virtual IP address

Tags: apache, https, configuration, httpd.conf

We are setting up for the HTTP configuration for our project with the httpd

But our physical IP address and the virtual IP address is not the same

Where the physical IP address is system IP address and virtual IP address is added in DNS configuration.

We need to setup httpd with the virtual IP address. not with the system IP address.

How can I do this without changing the DNS entry?

Please let me know the configurations for the httpd.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to bind http on port 80 (and 443 if you are not off-loading the secure layer).
Every request reaching your apache will be served according to the configuration (plain, virtualhost, etc).